# Is MinGW a rolling-release "distro"?

Tags: mingw, mingw32

My problem is that I've been unable to reproduce MinGW installations. I used the MinGW 5.1.3 all-in-one installer, but I have different users that ended up with different installations. I have an installation with binutils 2.20, and I'm unable to get the same stuff installed with the same installer.

I feel like MinGW works the same way rolling-release Linux distros work, but I couldn't find information about it... Note that I don't want to upgrade to mingw-get at the moment, just find out how I could have these components installed.

How can I find a way to have an installer generate the exact same configuration I currently have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer is just a handy tool. If you want to save your current installation, just copy the C:\mingw folder and store it somewhere safely.

The package management of mingw has always been somewhat lacking, although they've been working on it. If you really want hard-core package management, you'll always need a well-supported Linux distro that provides tons of mingw packages (like Fedora I think, or for sure [Opensuse](https://build.opensuse.org/project/packages?project=windows:mingw:win32)). An example of a full-fledged package manager for MinGW-w64 is [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/), which leverages pacman to make available a huge amount of packages for 32 and 64-bit.